# naturalWidth - Property 'naturalWidth' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am trying to access "naturalWidth" in typescript however if I get a compile error or or i get a red line under "naturalWidth". Because $("#contentImg").height()) returns 0 for me in JavaScript and TypeScript I cant manipulate the image. The image varies in size. If I do it in javascript its fine. I have tried;

```
  document.getElementById('contentImg').naturalWidth;
  $("#contentImg")[0].naturalWidth.
```

This works in JavaScript but not in TypeScript. Is there a way to get the naturalWidth/Height?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [document.getElementById](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L7114) returns an [HTMLElement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L8651) which lacks the `naturalWidth` property.
What you're looking for is the [HTMLImageElement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L9635) which does have this [`naturalWidth` property](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L9695):

```
let image =  document.getElementById('contentImg') as HTMLImageElement;
console.log(image.naturalWidth); // should be valid
```